# VBA - Getting back to Macros from userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a macro that at a certain part shows a userform, I publicly dimmed some variables in the userform in order to use it in the main macros.

Now I want to get back to the main macros after I hit "Proceed!" commandbutton.

[Batch Divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRKZi.png)

Here is my main macros:

```
Public C1 As String, C2 As String, C3 As String, C4 As String, C5 As String, C6 As String, C7 As String, C8 As String, C9 As String, C10 As String, C11 As String, C12 As String, C13 As String
Public NumB As Integer, NumofLines As Integer, Q1 As Integer, Q2 As Integer, Q3 As Integer, Q4 As Integer
Public Total As Double, Batch1Total As Double, Batch2Total As Double, Batch3Total As Double, Batch4Total As Double, Batch5Total As Double

Sub priority_calculation()

*Some code ....*

BatchDivider.Show

*Want to continue after hitting Proceed! commandbutton*


End Sub
```

Comment: Does the Proceed button Click event hide the form ?

Comment: No, it has another macro steps.

Comment: It will return to main when you hide the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the form:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim frm As New BatchDivider 'create an instance of the form
    
    frm.Show       'show the form instance: code stop here until form is hidden/unloaded
    Debug.Print frm.MyGlobal    'read the global from the (now hidden) form instance
    Unload frm    'now done with the form....
End Sub
```

In the form:

```vb
Public MyGlobal As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MyGlobal = "value from form"
    Me.Hide   'not unload
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse me, what is meant by “Value from form”?

Comment: That’s just an example to assign to the global variable in the form

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches. In both cases, make sure your form property ShowModal is set to False.

#### Event based

In your form code, add an Event

```
Public Event Proceed()
```

In your proceed button event handler, add something like this:

```
Private Sub btnProceed_Click()
    RaiseEvent Proceed
End Sub
```

In your calling code, which would need quite a reorganization and also be in a class module, declare the form as an object *with events*:

```
Dim WithEvents BatchDivider As BatchDividerForm
```

When Proceed is clicked, the event handler will fire:

```
Private Sub BatchDivider_Proceed()
    MsgBox "Proceed"
End Sub
```

This will not give you the thing you wanted - continue in the code after proceed - but it will give you a way of communicating between various parts of your code in a structured way.

#### Polling

This is the easier (and uglier) way of doing it.
Add this in your form code:

```
Private m_Ready As Boolean

Private Sub btnProceed_Click()
    m_Ready = True
End Sub

Property Let IsReady(IsReady As Boolean)
    m_Ready = IsReady
End Property

Property Get IsReady() As Boolean
    IsReady = m_Ready
End Property
```

In your calling code, do something like this:

```
Dim BatchDivider As BatchDividerForm
Set BatchDivider = New BatchDividerForm

BatchDivider.IsReady = False
BatchDivider.Show

Do While Not BatchDivider.IsReady
    DoEvents
Loop

MsgBox "Let's proceed"
```

In short, this adds a property to your form, which is set to False before. Just after the form is displayed, it will test if the property is set to True.

Comment: Showing a form modally passes control to the form until it's closed or hidden, so your `Do While` only runs when the form is dismissed...

Comment: That's why I wrote the thing about disabling ShowModal

Comment: Aha - missed that, sorry